# From VBA multi dimensional array to C++

Tags: c++, vba, boost

sorry for the dumb question(I am making a mess :) ). 
Using the boost library multi_array, how can define a 15 dimensional array?

I need to convert this VBA code

```
Dim   myArray() As Long
ReDim myArray(3 * 12)
```

to C++

cheers

Edit to the Question:

At the end there is another  Redim like that :

Dim myMaxArray() as long

```
ReDim myArray(myMaxArray(1),myMaxArray(2), myMaxArray(3), myMaxArray(4), myMaxArray(5), myMaxArray(6), myMaxArray(7), myMaxArray(8), myMaxArray(9), myMaxArray(10), myMaxArray(11), myMaxArray(12), myMaxArray(13), myMaxArray(14), myMaxArray(15))
```

This sould be a 15 dimensions array? am I wrong?

Comment: Do you have to use boost??

Comment: Does the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) not show you how to use it?

Comment: Your VBA code is *not* a 15-dimensional array. It’s onedimensional.

Comment: Ok sorry guys for the confusion I am converting this vba code now and i am litle birt confused, what I want to achieve is this :

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go for boost multi_array then